A couple of questions regarding "Question closed as a duplicate"
I've asked this question in 2019: Assert request hasn't happened and then provided the answer by myself, thus answering my question.
Today I've found in my mailbox a couple of confusing emails about marking this question as a duplicate etc etc
My questions regarding this are:

why is my question that was answered in 2019 marked as a duplicate of Cypress, verify that calls are not actually made made 22 days ago
why was my question, that was already answered, marked as closed; what does this mean?

To be clear - I don't care which question is marked as a duplicate of which; if Cypress, verify that calls are not actually made is for most recent version of Cypress (as a comment to another new answer to my question now suggests) and provides most value to community, that's great. Just want to understand the rules that were applied here

nothing in the duplicates process says that a older questions can't be the duplicate of a newer question.

Posts like these remind me of just how horrendous the language, guidance, and onboarding around closure is... it could really use some love by the company at some point.

As to the reason your question was closed as a duplicate of an newer question, 3 users with hundreds answers tagged to questions with cypress voted on the closure once one of those individuals flagged it as a duplicate. A user submitted an answer to a 5 year old question, it was then displayed on the first page, and drew the attention of users with the ability to vote to close the question as a duplicate. I can conclude issued the first close vote, but it does not matter, those 3 users did exactly what they should have done (IMO).

"why was my question, that was already answered, marked as closed; what does this mean?" - That is a very confusing question to ask when the topic of your meta post is in your own words closed as a duplicate. I don't like at all that duplicate links are handled as any other closure, but that does not make it hard to understand.

@Gimby I didn't understand what closed means. I thought that answering a question means that is already closed. I've now read what closing means, so that is clear
